# Root directory in Ubuntu and Mac OS X

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I've recently been messing with Ubuntu on my MacBook Air, installing it and uninstalling it, trying different flavours, etc... And for that I used rEFInd to set up a dual boot. One thing that I did notice was that under OS X I see a partition called EFI, and under Ubuntu I see the same partition but with a lot more files in it. Under Ubuntu I can see a /boot directory but under OS X if I try to access that directory using the terminal it tells me that it doesn't exist.
Is there a difference between the two root directories?

I'm relatively new at this but I would really like to learn how these things are organised.

When I installed Ubuntu where exactly was the root directory positioned? Is that root directory the same as the OS X's root directory? Or are they two separate root directories? If the latter is the case then what does '/' point to exactly? Is it to the lowest level of the hard drive?

Why is it that under Ubuntu I can write /boot but under OS X that directory is inexistent?

When you create and then mount a partition what exactly is happening? I ask this because this is what's happening:
Under OS X I can mount the EFI partition -  and from there access the directory created by rEFInd.
Under Ubuntu I can also mount the EFI partition but I have to go through /boot/something/else/EFI to access that same directory.
I thought that when I mounted a partition and I accessed it I would have access FIRST to the bottomest folders inside of it, but here it seems that the OS X EFI partition itself is inside another directory, which I thought wasn't possible (and probably isn't but I've confused myself to this point). So please, anyone, just walk me through what the root directory is, where in the disk it's located, what a partition is, why they seem to have different files depending on the OS, and anything else you might think is necessary or relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partition is just space on the disk with defined start- and end-points. When we create a partition, these start- and end-points of the partition are stored in the partition-table, in sector #0 in legacy-systems or in sector #2 - #32 in UEFI-systems. The  partition-table is not located in any partition but in reserved space at the start of the disk and is needed to manage the whole disk.

To be able to work with data in a partition, the partition needs to hold a file-system, the file-system is normally created, when we format the partition. When we create a fresh file-system, it will be a blank file-system, that means it doesn't hold any files or folders yet, but now we could create them. The file-system in the partition is permanent, it exists as long as we don't destroy it, it exists even if we switch off the computer because it is stored in a partition on the hard-drive.

A running operating system has it's own file-system which is a temporary file-system. This temporary file-system is created during startup and stops to exist when we shut down the operating system. The top-level-directory of this temporary file-system is `/`(under Linux), and `/` is usually the mount-point for the system-partition (more exactly we should say that `/` is the mount-point for the file-system in the system-partition). So when we open `/` in a file-manager we will see the files and folders which are stored in the system-partition on the disk. So, we could say that `/` points to the system-partition or to the file-system within the system-partition or the files and folders stored in the file-system within the system-partition, a question of terminology.

The EFI-System-Partition (ESP) is mounted to different locations in Linux and Mac OS X. In Linux the ESP is mounted to the folder `/boot/efi`, in Mac OS X the ESP is usually mounted to the folder `/Volumes/efi`. Both folders have the same content, as both folders point to the same partition, the ESP.

The ESP is not mounted to both folder at the same time, as only one OS is running at a time. Indeed, we can mount a partition to only one mount-point
at a time.

Remind that `/` points to different partitions depending on the currently running operating system. If we run Mac OS X, `/` points to your OS X-partition, if we run Ubuntu,`/` points to the Ubuntu-partition. Remind that `/` only exists temporary in a temporary file-system which was created during the startup of an operating system. If we shut-down and boot a different operating system we have a new temporary file-system with a new `/`-directory which may point to a different partition, defined by the currently running OS.

Answer (score 2):

First off, a partition is a section of allocated space on a hard drive.

The root (/) directory on Mac OS X and on Ubuntu are just the mount point for one of the partitions on your hard drive. Your ubuntu / and your Mac OS / are mountpoints for two different partitions. The interesting thing about this is that other partitions can be mounted inside of /. On Ubuntu your flash drive would probably be mounted at /media/{username}/{flashdrivename}/. Also in Ubuntu you could have your home directory on another partition if you wanted to. In that case /home would be a mount point to a partition on your drive. That would help to keep your system files and programs separate from your documents and user configurations.

In Ubuntu to see what partitions you have and what is mounted open up a terminal and type the following command:

```
lsblk
```

It will show something like this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   1 117.4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1 117.4G  0 part /media/logan/LOGAN128
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0  29.5G  0 part 
└─sda1   8:1    0  77.9G  0 part /
```

In my case, sda (storage device a) is my solid state drive, sdb is my flashdrive. I have my first partition on sda mounted as /. With my flashdrive, its only partition is mounted as /media/logan/LOGAN128 .

The "lowest level of your hard drive" is not /, but / is the lowest level on your computer in the sense that all mount points to are within /.

"/boot/" on Ubuntu is a place where bootloader configurations and files needed for booting are stored. Mac OS X does not have a /boot directory because it doesn't use a /boot folder for booting. Not sure what it uses - probably your "EFI" partition.

Answer (score 1):

Both Logan and mook765's answers are basically correct, but I want to emphasize and elaborate on some points:

- Most partitions/filesystems are OS-specific, or at least OS-centric. Most importantly, each OS has its own root (`/`) filesystem. (Windows works a little differently; instead of a root filesystem, it has a `C:` partition.)
- Default installations of both OS X and Ubuntu go on a single partition (the root, `/`, partition); however, there are usually ancillary partitions of various types. Most Ubuntu installations have a swap partition (which is *not* mounted in the way most partitions can be), for instance; and OS X often has a partition called `Recovery HD` that can be used to recover the installation in case of troubles. (This partition also usually holds the OS X boot loader, which can lead to confusion in rEFInd because rEFInd identifies OS X as booting from the `Recovery HD` partition, even though the main installation is elsewhere.)
- In both Ubuntu and OS X, filesystems other than the root (`/`) filesystem are accessed through directories (known as "mount points") in another filesystem. Thus, you might mount a partition at `/ask`, and thereafter the `ubuntu` file on that partition would become accessible as `/ask/ubuntu`. If you were to unmount that filesystem and remount it at `/mnt`, the file would become `/mnt/ubuntu`.
- You can optionally add other partitions or put part of your installation elsewhere. A separate `/home` partition is moderately common in Linux, for instance. Linux installations sometimes put `/boot` on a separate partition. This directory, whether it's a separate partition or not, holds the Linux kernel and associated support files, as well as configuration files for the GRUB boot loader (if you use it, as is the default for Ubuntu).
- The Linux kernel has filesystem drivers that let it mount most other OSes' filesystems, including those of OS X. Thus, you *could* access OS X's files in Linux, but they'd be somewhere else. For instance, the file `/foo/bar` in OS X might become `/media/OS-X/foo/bar` in Ubuntu.
- Some partitions are meant to be shared between OSes. You might set up such a partition yourself so as to share user files. The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is such a shared partition. In Ubuntu, it's mounted at `/boot/efi` by default. In OS X, it's not mounted by default, but rEFInd's installation script (`refind-install`) needs to mount it because rEFInd lives on the ESP. The rEFInd installation script mounts it at `/Volumes/ESP` by default -- but something else might conceivably mount it elsewhere. Note that in OS X this is likely to be temporary unless you explicitly mount it elsewhere.
- On the ESP, rEFInd lives in the `EFI/refind` directory by default. Thus, in Ubuntu, this is `/boot/efi/EFI/refind`; and in OS X, if it's mounted by the `refind-install` script, it will be `/Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind`.
- The files available on a partition should be identical no matter what OS is used to access them, but as already noted, the mount point may be different. Also, some tools in any given OS can hide some files. Files beginning with a dot/period (`.`) are hidden by most shells, for instance. There may also be some files or data structures that might be hidden by some OSes but not by others.
- In both OSes, you can use the `df` command to see what filesystems are mounted and where. The output format varies a bit between OS X and Linux, though.
- You can mount one filesystem within another. I'm not sure if there's a depth limit on this. Of note for some of your questions, if you have a separate `/boot` partition in Ubuntu, then your ESP would normally be mounted to the `efi` directory on the `/boot` partition, which in turn would be mounted to the `boot` directory on the root (`/`) partition. Thus, if you were to "travel" from the root (`/`) directory to the ESP, you'd "pass through" three filesystems.